# Playing a sound once pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to play background music and the music keeps on starting. I tried to use `music.busy`, but I can't figure it out. I want it to check if sound/music is playing, then I want it to print "music is playing". If a sound/music isn't playing I want it to start up a new song and loop it.

```
def musica():
    if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        print("music is playing")
    if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:    
        music.play(loops=-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this it is more of a workaround but it works:

```
m = 0
def musica():
    global m
    if m == 0:
        music.play(loops=-1)
        m = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to play looped sounds is winsound. See the python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/winsound.html) and set the parameter 'flags' in PlaySound to winsound.SND_LOOP.

Comment: I can only use pygames for my assiagment

Comment: @Chan You should put that in your question! ;P

Comment: Dude its in the title "Playing a sound once pygame"

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to play a sound during a specific event in a loop (e.g. opening a menu), it is possible to play sound only once by using timers.

example:

```
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound.wav')
    playSound = True
    playSound_counter = 0
    
    while:
            playSound_counter += 1
            if playSound_counter >= 11:
                playSound = True
                playSound_counter = 0

      if i.rect.collidepoint(mouse_position):
                if playSound == True :
                    sound.play()
                    playSound = False
                elif playSound_counter == 10:
                     playSound_counter = 0
```

This is essentially two timers - one sets sound back to True every 11 secs, another negates it while mouse is over a rect.

by "playing once" i meant to be able to play it again in a controlled way when a certain event is triggered